# How to read a text file in C# , separating rows without a delimiter

Tags: c#

Input text file:

```
LOCATION_NUMBER|LOCATION_TYPE_CODE|BRANDED_NAME|STORE_TYPE_CODE|STORE_TYPE_DESC|LOCATION_STATUS_CODE|LOCATION_STATUS_DESC|PROPOSED_OPEN_DATE|OPEN_DATE|CLOSE_DATE|PARENT_LOCATION_NUMBER|PARENT_LOCATION_TYPE_CODE**1**|A||||1|Open|07/08/2015 00:00:00|07/08/2015 00:00:00||24|R**1**|D||||2|Closed|05/01/2015 00:00:00|05/01/2015 00:00:00|07/07/2015 00:00:00|199|A
```

The row ends after 12 columns of data. How can I store and separate a row which starts from "1" in a separate record in data table.

Code:

```
string line;
while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] items = line.Trim().Split('|');
    if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
        // on the first line of the file
        //for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("location_number", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("location_type_code", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("branded_name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("store_type_code", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("store_type_desc", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("location_status_code", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("location_status_desc", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("proposed_open_date", typeof(DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("open_date", typeof(DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("close_date", typeof(DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("parent_location_number", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("parent_location_type_code", typeof(string)));
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(items); 
}
```

Comment: but it does have a delimeter "|" just split on that. If there really is no record end for a row, just split after every 12

Comment: Are you bound to this file structure? 
If so:
1. Is "location_number" always 1? Could it be >=10 2. If it can be any number can you be sure that the last field does not end with a number? 3. If not: What's the point of a column thats always 1?

Comment: Well, i suspect lines are delimited by any invisible char(f.e. tab-character). Otherwise this is garbage data. It's impossible to know where a line ends and the next one starts without a delimiter. You only know that the new line starts somewhere in the 12th column, but not where.

Comment: @Tim - yes there is enter character which is not readable in txt file

Comment: @Amie: of course: `text.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)` returns all lines. Not visible doesnt mean it's not there. But `File.ReadAllLines` should return the lines already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have only a single line and you want to split it into rows where each row has 12 columns?

The "LINQY" way:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
int columns = 12;      // if it will change as variable
bool hasHeader = true; // change accordingly

var rows = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile)              // reads file as string
    .Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None)   // split on pipe delimiter to get a string[]
    .Select((field, index) => new { field, index })  // project anonymous type with field and index
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / columns)                 // integer division trick to group by 12 columns
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.field).ToArray())   // create a string[] for every row's fields
    .ToArray();                                      // create a string[][]

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    table.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? rows.FirstOrDefault()?[i] : null); // add either generated column name or use first row

for (int i = hasHeader ? 1 : 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(rows[i]);  // add all 12 fields
}
```

Comment: The way I read the question is that there are no separators per row (CR/LF for row & no delimiter after last column) - so everything appears on 1 line & the 12th & 1st columns are merged.

Comment: @PaulF: i have understood it differently. The 1 was just to tell us where he wants to split the row in this case. Actually he only knows there are 12 columns and he wants to split on that(imo). So there is only a single line but he wants a new line every 12th column

Comment: If the example file is correct there does not appear to be a delimiter of any sort between "PARENT_LOCATION_TYPE_CODE" & "1" or "R" & "1".

Comment: @PaulF: you're right, but there is another 1 later, i thought this is the right one

Comment: This one is right - 
 
If the example file is correct there does not appear to be a delimiter of any sort between "PARENT_LOCATION_TYPE_CODE" & "1" or "R" & "1". we only have delimiter per column and not after row has changed as it is coming from DB

Comment: @Amie: i got it. But are you sure there is no delimiter? Maybe tab was used as newq-line delimiter or any other invisible character. Your requirement is impossible. How do you know where the last line ends and the next line starts?

Comment: Yeah I m sure . the last column will have a single character and the first character will always be a single number . like : "R" & "1". without a delimiter

Comment: @Amie: there is absolutely no way to fix this garbage, sorry. You don't know if the last column of the prev. line ends with a number, you are not sure if the next line's first column will always start with a number. You don't know where a line ends and where the next one starts.

Comment: actually there is a enter at the end of each row but it is not seen in txt file . if you convert it to .csv file , it will come in proper format and not garbage value .

Comment: @Armie: then it's easy. Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines(path)`?

Comment: @Amie: what returns `File.ReadAllText(path).Split(new [] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length`? That should return a number greater than 1.

Comment: No Tim ... It is returning just 1 . Is it possible to read this txt file and convert it to CSv to read all the data coz in CSV format it is giving separated records

Comment: @Amie: CSV is nothing else than text. You just need to know the line-delimter. Is the text above the unmodifed text(copy pasted)? I see you have added `**`. Show original text

Comment: LOCATION_NUMBER|LOCATION_TYPE_CODE|BRANDED_NAME|STORE_TYPE_CODE|STORE_TYPE_DESC|LOCATION_STATUS_CODE|LOCATION_STATUS_DESC|PROPOSED_OPEN_DATE|OPEN_DATE|CLOSE_DATE|PARENT_LOCATION_NUMBER|PARENT_LOCATION_TYPE_CODE1|A||||1|Open|07/08/2015 00:00:00|07/08/2015 00:00:00||24|R1|D||||2|Closed|05/01/2015 00:00:00|05/01/2015 00:00:00|07/07/2015 00:00:00|199|A

Comment: It doesnt contain any line delimiter(afaik). I wonder how excel reads it in several lines. Or what tool you have used?

Answer (score 0):

If your file would be strucktured like this:

```
First Name|Last Name|Age
fName1|lName1|10
fName2|lName2|34
fName3|lName3|45
fName4|lName4|66
```

You could write:

```
if (File.Exists("file.txt"))
{
    List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(x => x.Split(';')).ToList();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(rows[0][0], typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(rows[0][1], typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(rows[0][2], typeof(int));


    foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
    {
        string fName = row[0];
        string lName = row[1];
        int age = -1;
        int.TryParse(row[2], out age);

        table.Rows.Add(fName, lName, age);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

To create that file:

```
private void Save()
{
    List<string> stringRows = new List<string>();
    stringRows.Add(string.Join("|",dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(x => x.Name)));

    List<DataGridViewRow> gridViewRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList();
    gridViewRows.RemoveAt(gridViewRows.Count - 1); //Last Line is empty

    stringRows.AddRange(gridViewRows.Select(x => string.Join("|", x.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(y => y.Value))));
    File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", stringRows);
}
```

Comment: OP has said how the file is structured - the data needs splitting on the highlighted "1"s

Comment: "how can I store and separate" I interpreted "store" as saving the data into a file. You must agree that this way of saving the data is a lot less error-pron.

Comment: But you do not show how you would go about taking the existing format & splitting at the required point - so you are not addressing the question. (It wasn't me who downvoted btw)

Comment: That's right! But there are some details about the structure missing.
1. Is "location_number" always `1`? Could it be `>=10`
2. If it can be any number can you be sure that the last field does not end with a number?
3. If not: What's the point of a column thats always 1?

Comment: I hoped the OP would replay if this suit for him or why it does not. So I could adjust the solution...

Comment: Then you should have put those questions in a comment so that you could come up with a suitable answer to the question.